# Could/should we use footnotes when writing a post in SE.TeX?

Tags: feature-request, markdown

Sometimes, when I write a post on SE.TeX, I feel the need to create a footnote.

But, as far as I know, there is no way to do it in TeX.SE. Neither [markdown syntax](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help) nor [minimal html](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites) allow footnotes.

In my opinion, footnotes are goods ; they allow the main text to stay clear and concise *and* they offer the possibility to expand or precise a point.

Why should not include some (minimal) footnotes support in the SE.TeX mardown syntax ?

Such syntaxes are availables :

```
<=my footnote=>
+my footnote+
#my footnote#
```

Comment: My question here is how really useful footnotes would be. Most 'references' can be dealt with by hyperlinking to sources, and for 'extended discussion' of ideas then normally saying 'see below' works in the format we have.

Comment: @JosephWright I just feel the need to use footnote in [one of my post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148864/how-to-not-print-the-day-month-of-a-biblatex-reference). It could help to see the possible usages.

Comment: I don't see the need for a footnote in your example: it's not an academic paper. I'd phase as 'The `biblatex` manual says [quote]. However, this puts all of the information into one field, so that I can'd do ...'.

Comment: @JosephWright You right. I could phrase in another way. Footnotes are probably just a professional (bad) habit of mine.

Answer (score 5):

You could do like this<sup>1</sup>, though you have to number and position the footnotes manually.

A related question on Meta.SO: [Markdown footnotes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5017/markdown-footnotes)

---

<sup>1</sup> Using `<sup>1</sup>` to write a raised number.

Comment: Indeed! But there is no link between the footnote call and the footnote itself and it takes too much time to create footnotes this way. So nobody will use it. Perhaps it will be different if it was easy and clickable?

Comment: @ppr I have seen people (well, at least one person) use it, though I agree that a better syntax, and hyperlinked, would be a lot better.